# How can i install Ti.Healthkit module?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, healthkit, titanium-modules

I have downloaded ti.healthkit from https://labs.appcelerator.com/project/55c3c788e014044625e9b2a1/HealthKit-Module but i could not build it although i did by instructions.

So i get the bug 
`Chances are there is an issue with your entitlements. Verify the bundle IDs in the generated Info.plist file.`

i also add 
       `<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
             <array>
               <string>healthkit</string>
             </array>`

into tiapp.xml. But i still get the same bug.

So, how can i fix it?

Looking forward your answer.

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

As I read the docs of this kit, they say to add this in your tiapp.xml file **plist** tag:

```
<key>com.apple.developer.healthkit</key>
<true/>
```

So, your final tiapp.xml file should look like this (notice the healthkit key-value at the end):

```
<ios>
        <enable-launch-screen-storyboard>true</enable-launch-screen-storyboard>
        <plist>
            <dict>
                <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~iphone</key>
                <array>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
                </array>
                <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
                <array>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
                    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
                </array>
                <key>UIRequiresPersistentWiFi</key>
                <false/>
                <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
                <false/>
                <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
                <false/>
                <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
                <string>UIStatusBarStyleDefault</string>
                <key>com.apple.developer.healthkit</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </plist>
    </ios>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering me. I have resolved this issused. I just regis Apple Certificate, add Healthkit for it. And i have build successfully.